# Angular 11: Change scroll-behavior only for scrollPositionRestoration

Tags: javascript, angular, angular11

I'm trying to make angular scroll to the top of the page when you go to a new route.
`scrollPositionRestoration: 'top'` in `app-routing` accomplishes this task. However, this scroll is animated in accordance with `scroll-behavior: smooth;` in my main css file.

This `scroll-behavior` is important for my use of `ViewportScroller` in the application. However, strictly in the case of loading a new page, I think that animated scroll is disorienting and unnecessary.

Is there any way to disable this behavior just when loading a new route while maintaining it elsewhere in my app?

Answer (score 0):

I found an ugly solution but it works.

Just set the property scrollPositionRestoration of your routerOptions to top : `const routerOptions: ExtraOptions = { scrollPositionRestoration: 'top' };`.

Then on the component you are going to, add `document.querySelector('html')!.style.scrollBehavior = 'auto';` to the constructor body and `document.querySelector('html')!.style.scrollBehavior = 'smooth';` to the *ngOnInit()* method body.

Now when you go to this component from another component, you should have your scroll bar immediately at the top of the page (without smooth effect). If you used a fragment then you will go to the associated anchor with the smooth effect.